# ATM locations in UK and/or Ireland

Tags: data-request, geospatial, finance, uk, ireland

I know lots of organizations and websites are publishing some of these but is there an **open** dataset with at a minimum of location and operator for ATMs in the UK and possible Ireland?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where could I find open data about ATM locations (in Paris)?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/894/where-could-i-find-open-data-about-atm-locations-in-paris)

Comment: I guess it's not really a duplicate, as the city of Paris could maintain a database and the countries UK and Ireland another?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the data is only as good as the community contributes, [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) (OSM) has some ATM data.

In OSM, points can be tagged with "amenity=atm". You can extract these nodes using these steps:

1. Download OSM data. [This page](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html) has a "British isles" extract, among others. [This page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet) explains more generally how this kind of data is packaged.
2. Download and extract the [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) command-line java tool
3. Run a command such as `./osmosis --read-pbf british-isles-latest.osm.pbf --tf accept-nodes amenity=atm --write-xml british-atms.osm`

Osmosis also [supports](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage) writing to databases instead of XML.

The details available for each node vary widely, but then, you get what you pay for, and as you noted, there are a number of commercial sources for this data.

Comment: Good answer. There's also the Google Places API which I'll look at.