# USPS drop box locations in NYC?

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, city

I posted this in [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220162/usps-drop-box-locations-in-nyc) but was referred here. I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction...

I'm doing some analysis on the impacts of neighborhood characteristics on physical activity. One of the covariates is distance from geocoded home addresses to points of interest, which include USPS office and drop box locations.

Does anyone know if a dataset/shapefile exists containing USPS drop box locations? I was able to find USPS locations from NYC Open Data, but can't seem to find one with the list of drop box locations.

Comment: Also see this one at GIS http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/50437

Comment: Thanks. I saw this earlier, but the dataset only includes post offices and not drop box locations.

Comment: Can you check if OSM would work for you? Here's an example http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4642/1511

Comment: Have you contacted USPS directly or looked on their site? I would be surprised if they didn't have this.